# PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null, null)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-signin

I know this question have been asked and answered multiple times. But my case is a bit different.

My flutter app is available on both Google Play and App store. The Google Sign In worked perfectly. But it suddenly makes the error below while I am updating it. This error occurs in both debug and release mode. I didn't make any major pubspect(pod) change. I checked SHA,OAuth Screen, supporting email, which were checked before publishing the app. This version hasn't been published yet. The current version on Google Play and App Store works fine with Google SignIn. Any help??

PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null, null)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add new provider at firebase auth

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by adding SHA1 to Firebase and replacing google-services.json file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using google_sign_in package
Instead  of using this

```
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser;
GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
```

try using

```
 GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser;
    googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
```

some version of google_sign_in have this issue